# A question of spark AccumulatorV2. I'm a green hand about apache spark, so i'dont know why the question is throw

Tags: apache-spark

the code is posted here

```scala
package sparkcore.test

import org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object testAccumulator {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("sparkAcc")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.makeRDD(ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer[Long](1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ArrayBuffer[Long](1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)))

    var acc = new NotNullField
    sc.register(acc)

    rdd.foreach(
      text =>{
        acc.add(text)
      }
    )
    println(acc.value)
  }

  class NotNullField extends AccumulatorV2[ArrayBuffer[Long], ArrayBuffer[Long]] {
    val arrayBuffer = ArrayBuffer[Long](0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
    override def isZero: Boolean = {
      var flag = true
      for(i <- 0 to arrayBuffer.length-1 if flag){
        if (arrayBuffer(i) != 0) flag = false
      }
      flag
    }

    override def copy(): AccumulatorV2[ArrayBuffer[Long], ArrayBuffer[Long]] = {
      new NotNullField
    }

    override def reset(): Unit = {
      arrayBuffer.clear()
    }

    override def add(v: ArrayBuffer[Long]): Unit = {
      for(i <- 0 to v.length - 1){
        if(v(i) != 0) arrayBuffer(i) += v(i)
      }
    }

    override def merge(other: AccumulatorV2[ArrayBuffer[Long], ArrayBuffer[Long]]): Unit = {
      other match {
        case o: NotNullField =>{
          for(i <- 0 to arrayBuffer.length -1){
line 45:error here   arrayBuffer(i) += o.arrayBuffer(i)
          }
        }
        case _  =>
      }
    }

    override def value: ArrayBuffer[Long] = {
      arrayBuffer
    }
  }
}
```

the error is simple

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.apply(ResizableArray.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.apply(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at sparkcore.test.testAccumulator$NotNullField$$anonfun$add$1.apply$mcVI$sp(testAccumulator.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at sparkcore.test.testAccumulator$NotNullField.add(testAccumulator.scala:44)
    at sparkcore.test.testAccumulator$$anonfun$main$1.apply(testAccumulator.scala:19)
    at sparkcore.test.testAccumulator$$anonfun$main$1.apply(testAccumulator.scala:18)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1954)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1954)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:325)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKHUf.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQsqp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANAmL.png)arrayBuffer is empty in line 45, so it throw IndexOutOfBoundsException, i use Array rather than ArrayBuffer in the code, it can work, why? I know the theory of Accumulator, the ArrayBuffer are copied to Executor, so it should not be empty.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh, my bad, apache-spark version and scala version are miss, spark version is 2.11 and scala is 2.1.3 . All code copyable form is posted in the beginning,  it can be copied directly.